# Workflow to UV unwrap the exterior of a real world product with slight defects, given a lack of resources

Tags: modeling, uv, image, uv-image-editor, photorealism

Ok sorry for the weird title but bear with me on this one! I want to model this bottle from scratch for use in a product animation:

[image]

which I don't have foresee a problem in the modelling within blender.

However, the problem arises because the exterior sticker of the bottle that I have is slightly worn out. Also, I don't have the original sticker image as a jpg file to simply UV unwrap onto my mesh. I'm also not the most proficient in third party apps used for image editing.

So here's the question:

What is the best workflow for me to model a perfect version of this bottle in blender without any imperfections, given my current (lack of) resources? Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is my current thought process to model the outer sticker:

1. carefully peel the sticker and take an image of it on a flat surface
2. use a third party app(photoshop?) to remove and repair the imperfections
3. uv unwrap the edited image onto the mesh in blender.

Assuming we use photoshop, can someone explain the relevant tools I need to use within the program? I'll be glad to work from a general idea so at least I know what areas in photoshop to look into for this particular case!

Comment: Hi :) It would probably be easiest to model the sticker from scratch. The font is *Helvetica Black* and *Regular* and the logo is easily found on google. Either way, not really related to Blender.

Comment: Btw, you could make the sticker by simply bending a plane. No UV unwrapping needed ;)